# Apache POI: Export Data to Another Workbook

Tags: java, excel

I want to export all the data from one workbook to another using Java. I used FOR LOOP to read all the data from the input.xls file. Then I want to Export all the read data to output.xls. I don't know how to export it after reading data. I need your help guys. Thanks.

```
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:\\input.xls"));
    FileOutputStream wbML = new FileOutputStream("C:\\output.xls");
    Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    for (Row row : sheet1) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            String sValue = cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
            System.out.println(sValue);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to copy the workbook, there is no need to iterate. Just write it to a new file.

```
  Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:\\input.xls"));
  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\ouput.xls");
  wb.write(fileOut);
  fileOut.close();
```

Comment: Thank You @milez! I appreciate your help. Problem Solved. Now I understand a bit about Apache POI in Java-Excel.

Comment: @bigbryan My pleasure. This tutorial is full of useful snippets like the one above: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook. If this solved your problem, please cosider accepting the answer :)

Comment: Ok, I'll check it out. Thanks again for the help @milez. Have a great day.